# Calling Marketing Cloud APIs from PHP via FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, php

I am using PHP FuelSDK installed with composer. I followed this guide to create the clientid and clientsecret:

http://www.calvinfroedge.com/salesforce-how-to-generate-api-credentials/

Here is my code:

```
require COMPOSER_DIR . 'autoload.php';

use FuelSdk\ET_Client;
use FuelSdk\ET_List;

$config = array(
    'appsignature'            => 'none',
    'clientid'                => 'XXX',
    'clientsecret'            => 'XXX',
    'defaultwsdl'             => 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl',
    'xmlloc'                  => '/var/www/html/playground/salesforce/composer/vendor/salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php/ExactTargetWSDL.xml',
    'baseUrl'                 => 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com',
    'baseAuthUrl'             => 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com',
    'baseSoapUrl'             => 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx',
    'useOAuth2Authentication' => false,
);

$myclient = new ET_Client(true, true, $config);

$request = new ET_List();
$request->authStub = $client;
$response = $request->get();

print_r($response);
```

All I am trying to do right now is connect to my Salesforce Sandbox using the connect app I created. I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided.: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided, requestToken response:{"message":"Unauthorized","errorcode":1,"documentation":""} in /var/www/html/playground/salesforce/composer/vendor/salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php/src/ET_Client.php:320 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/playground/salesforce/composer/vendor/salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php/src/ET_Client.php(215): FuelSdk\ET_Client->refreshToken() #1 /var/www/html/playground/salesforce/index.php(43): FuelSdk\ET_Client->__construct(true, true, Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/playground/salesforce/composer/vendor/salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php/src/ET_Client.php on line 320
```

I know the keys work as I ran this curl command as the guide suggested and I got a successful response back:

```
$cmd = 'curl -v https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id='.$config['clientid'].'" -d "client_secret='.$config['clientsecret'].'" -d "username=XXX" -d "password=XXX"';
exec($cmd, $result);
```

What am I missing in setting up the SDK? I feel like I am missing something very simple and I am not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

So the link you provided is not for the marketing cloud its for the salesforce. You should follow this doc: [Create and Install Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm) for getting a clientid/secret for Marketing Cloud

I would also recommend starting with the oAuth 2.0 authentication (you can't create a legacy package anyway) and using TSE (Tenant Specific Endpoints)